# How to move a file in to zip uncompressed, with zip cmd tool

Tags: command-line, zip, command-line-tool

I'm try to determine how to use the `zip` cmd line tool to move a file (uncompressed) in to a zip of compressed files (ie I want a zip in the end with all files but one compressed, b/c the one file is another compressed file).

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-m is what I wanted, moves the file(s) into a zip.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but doesn't -m option just delete the source file after it adds it to the archive? And it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: that's what I want, just forgot to mention it, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could use -n option to just store the files with defined extensions together with -g option to append the file to archive.

I didn't test it, but something like this should do the trick:

```
zip -gn .foo archive.zip myAddedFile.foo
```

Although documentation states that, by default, zip does not compress files with extensions in the list .Z:.zip:.zoo:.arc:.lzh:.arj, so if you are adding a file with one of those extensions you should be fine.

Documentation to the command is [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm)

Comment: thanks for the great answer, sorry I didn't ask my question clearly enough. +1 though.