# move files to .zip archive in windows command line

Tags: cmd, zip

I wanted to know how to move files to a .zip archive. I'm using this code: `xcopy C:\Folder C:\AnotherFolder\zippedFolder.zip`. This copies the files from C:\Folder **DIRECTLY** into the archive, but I want to have that file in the archive (so i can doubleclick the archive and see the file unopened).

Want to do this to create an excel file with a .cmd

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) Please look at [ask] and take the [tour]. It seems this question has nothing to do with programming. I flagged it for closing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-m` to import a file to a ZIP archive.

I found this on StackOverflow maybe it helps you.

[How to move a file in to zip uncompressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730747/how-to-move-a-file-in-to-zip-uncompressed-with-zip-cmd-tool/3731813#3731813), with zip cmd tool

But be careful it deletes the source file after it adds it to the archive. See the link for more details.

**UPDATE**

Instructions from this site. http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_zip.htm.
`-m` moves the specified files into the ZIP archive; actually, this deletes the target directories/files after making the specified ZIP archive.

If a directory becomes empty after removal of the files, the directory is also removed. No deletions are done until `zip` has created the archive without errors. This is useful for conserving disk space, but is potentially dangerous so it is recommended to use it in combination with `-T` to test the archive before removing all input files.

```
zip -m yourfile zip.file
```